# Launching safari with an image or saving to camera roll issues

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I've downloaded an image from a web service and either need to open the image within safari or save it to the camera roll. I've tried to open the image in Safari, but safari doesn't open.

```
var safari = UIApplication.SharedApplication;
var uri = new NSUrl(path); // where the image is saved to
safari.OpenUrl(uri);
```

This compiles, but Safari doesn't launch

The code I have for saving to the camera roll is this

```
PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary.PerformChanges(() =>
{
      using (var pool3 = new NSAutoreleasePool())
      {                                     pool3.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate ()
           {                                                               PHAssetChangeRequest.FromImage((UIImage)UIImage.FromFile(path));
           });
      }
      }, (t, err) =>
      {
           if (!t)
           {
                 using (var pool1 = new NSAutoreleasePool())
                 {
                      pool1.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate () {
                           var alert = new UIAlertView("Error saving file", "An error has occured saving your photo to the camera roll", null, "OK");
                          alert.Show();
                          };
           }
           else
           {
                 using (var pool2 = new NSAutoreleasePool())
                 {
                       pool2.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate (){
                            var alert = new UIAlertView("Image saved", "Your image has been saved to the camera roll", null, "OK"); 
                            alert.Show();
                            });
                        };
                 }
         });
```

which crashes and burns (the correct permissions have been set)

I'm at a loss as to why neither of these work as they seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open a local path with safari, that isn't allowed on iOS (apps are sandboxed) so you'll need to use either a remote URL or have your own `UIWebView` or `WKWebView` or a `SFSafariViewController` to display that image in a safari like experience. [Here is a blog post in the Xamarin Site](https://blog.xamarin.com/keep-users-engaged-with-ios-9s-sfsafariviewcontroller/) about the subject.

Also here is a nice [recipe in the Xamarin site](http://docs.xamarin.com/Recipes/iOS/Media/Video_and_Photos/Save_Photo_to_Album_with_Metadata/) to save a photo into the camera roll, you can do your own solution based on it.

Hope this helps!